# jQuery $.ajax() method is not setting contentType correctly when using Web API

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I'm trying to send the following object to my Web API Rest service using jQuery's $.ajax() method. When I make the call with out setting content type explicitly it sets it to application/x-www-form-urlencoded automatically, and the response is a 500. I need it to be application/json. When I set it to contentType: 'application/json' the request method in the header suddenly says OPTIONS in the dev tools and the request returns a 405. Does anyone see anything I'm doing wrong here? I normally never have trouble making requests like this.

Here is the data object I'm sending.

```
var TEST_DATA = {
        PaitentId: "323f0725-b404-4ab3-b227-e64b090ff62f",
        PracticeId: "2387B1BE-6CEC-41C1-B411-687BD6160556",
        ReportName: "SOME_REPORT_NAME",
        DeviceId: 1,
        GlucoseUnits: 1,
        HighGlucoseThreshold: 185,
        LowGlucoseThreshold: 80,
        TodayDate: "\/Date(1382932800000)\/",
        StartDate: "\/Date(1357016400000)\/",
        EndDate: "\/Date(1411876800000)\/"
}
```

Here is the call I'm making to the api

```
var GenerateReport = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: SERVICE_URL,
        processData: false,            
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: TEST_DATA,
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: displaySpinner(),

        success: function (data) {
            successCallback(data);
        },

        error: function () {
            errorCallback();
        }
    });

}
```

EDIT: This ended up being something I could fix through Web API, Answer provided below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up fixing the issue by allowing CORS to be used directly through web API. The Documentation can be found here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

You add `config.EnableCors();` to your `WebApiConfig` class. Then in your controller you can add an attribute like below

```
    namespace WebService.Controllers
    {
        [EnableCors(origins: "http://your.origin.site.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        public class TestController : ApiController
        {
            // Controller methods not shown...
        }

     }
```

You can do this globally as well through the `WebApiConfig` as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to do a cross domain request, it is *by design*. The documentation of `jQuery.ajax` says : *Note: For cross-domain requests, setting the content type to anything other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the server.*

You should not use Json for cross-domain web service.

Comment: hmm you're right, looks like JSONP is what would need to be used.